# Connect to a minecraft server via localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, proxy, minecraft

I tried making a proxy server for a minecraft server which you connect to, so you can modify the Minecraft protocol and / or other stuff.

I tried doing a TCP proxy server like this which redirects sockets to the given address:

```
var net = require("net");

process.on("uncaughtException", function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});

if (process.argv.length != 5) {
  console.log("usage: %s <localport> <remotehost> <remoteport>", process.argv[1]);
  process.exit();
}

var localport = process.argv[2];
var remotehost = process.argv[3];
var remoteport = process.argv[4];

var server = net.createServer(function (localsocket) {
  var remotesocket = new net.Socket();

  remotesocket.connect(remoteport, remotehost);

  localsocket.on('connect', function (data) {
    console.log(">>> connection #%d from %s:%d",
      server.connections,
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
  });

  localsocket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("%s:%d - writing data to remote",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    var flushed = remotesocket.write(data);
    if (!flushed) {
      console.log("  remote not flushed; pausing local");
      localsocket.pause();
    }
  });

  remotesocket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("%s:%d - writing data to local",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    var flushed = localsocket.write(data);
    if (!flushed) {
      console.log("  local not flushed; pausing remote");
      remotesocket.pause();
    }
  });

  localsocket.on('drain', function() {
    console.log("%s:%d - resuming remote",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    remotesocket.resume();
  });

  remotesocket.on('drain', function() {
    console.log("%s:%d - resuming local",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    localsocket.resume();
  });

  localsocket.on('close', function(had_error) {
    console.log("%s:%d - closing remote",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    remotesocket.end();
  });

  remotesocket.on('close', function(had_error) {
    console.log("%s:%d - closing local",
      localsocket.remoteAddress,
      localsocket.remotePort
    );
    localsocket.end();
  });

});

server.listen(localport);

console.log("redirecting connections from 127.0.0.1:%d to %s:%d", localport, remotehost, remoteport);
```

Unfortunately, this is redirecting to a wrong adress? However this method seems to be working fine on some cracked minecraft servers, but on hypixel for example it doesnt.

[image]
Those are the logs that I receive when trying to enter 127.0.0.1:25565 (localhost:25565)

```
redirecting connections from 127.0.0.1:25565 to mc.hypixel.net:25565
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to remote
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to remote
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - closing local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - closing remote
```

Furthermore, I've tried using https://github.com/darcros/node-minecraft-proxy, but I don't get any errors, I just time out when trying to connect.

I think that my client is trying to connect to the ip and it puts the handshake and the port into there. The server receives the packet and unpacks it. Since the origin is localhost and not the original server ip and port of the server,  I'm getting a security error.

Now furthermorere, I have also tried using a mineflayer bot to connect to the server, which eventually leads my client to being timed out again before being able to do anything.

```js
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  console.log('New connection from local server');
  const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: 'mc.hypixel.net',
    port: 25565,
  });

  // Handle incoming packets from the local server
  socket.on('data', (packet) => {
    console.log('Received packet from local server');
    bot._client.write(packet);
  });

  // Handle incoming packets from the target server
  bot.on('packet', (packet) => {
    console.log('Received packet from target server');
    server.send(packet, 0, packet.length, 25565, 'localhost');
  });
});
server.listen(25565);
```

Possibly something wrong with sending the packet that the local server receives with redirecting it to the target server, since when I tried logging all the packets, the `bot` does not receive packets, however the local server does receive a packet which begins with `0f 00 2f`.

I'm not an expert to what this means, but could it be a verify packet?

Comment: Can you show logs when you try to login ? Mostly with `redirecting connections from ...` ?

Comment: redirecting connections from 127.0.0.1:25565 to mc.hypixel.net:25565
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to remote
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to remote
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - writing data to local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - closing local
::ffff:127.0.0.1:50233 - closing remote

thats all what happens. I have also added it to the question.

Comment: Ok, so it seems you are writing it as you are on local, but Hypixel doesn't allow it because for them you are trying to hack

Comment: Nice, so are there any ways I can solve this issue or any alternatives that I could try?

Comment: maybe login as the IP of your proxy, instead of telling it's local. But idk how to do that

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways for trying to help.

Comment: You should try https://github.com/PrismarineJS/node-minecraft-protocol you can see this library implemented here: https://github.com/Heath123/pakkit

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a problem with your code, it's a security feature to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. Your Minecraft client is handshaking with the server and during this process, the client sends a [Handshake Packet](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshake). This packet contains info, including the server address. Hypixel reads the packet and assumes your connection is compromised.

If you want to trick your Minecraft client into sending the correct host name,
you can [Edit Your Hosts File](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) To Redirect mc.hypixel.net to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 mc.hypixel.net
```

Then, run your proxy on port 25565 and connect to mc.hypixel.net,
Your OS will automatically route it to your proxy.

There are also some hacked clients out there with this feature, but I wouldn't recommend using them because they are sketchy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would prefer to not make any changes to my OS specifically, because in the end I might be going to share this project and pushing them into chaning things on their OS can be inefficient.

Comment: If you don't want to change your host file configuration you can setup a DNS on your local network with this entry.
I did it with my raspberrypi, but all the others (not on your network) will have to setup a DNS server or you have to expose your DNS server on internet.
And all the client have to change their DNS configuration (that is not very different than changing host file).
You won't find a way to bypass the 'man in the middle' protection without changing minecraft code (and it's a good thing for internet security).

Comment: This is the correct answer. You need to send the actual server address during the handshake, not 127.0.0.1  
You might be able to edit the packets ota but doing a hosts file change or a custom DNS is much simpler and much more likely to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you couldn't simply redirect the packets to get the work done and thanks to @Samarth Pradeep we know why.
In this situation you actually have 2 ways:

1. Because you know how to interact with the remote server, you can patch bytes in the data to change target ip (very complicated to understand and find a way, but more elegant)
2. Make your proxy emulate server-side for its clients and client-side for the remote server.

For the first way you can look to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Classic_server_protocol#Packet_Protocol), for the second - use libraries like [mcproto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcproto)